# Difference between configuring DHCP and starting service

Tags: networking, dhcp, windows-server-2008-r2

On http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441263(v=ws.10).aspx, it says to configure and start DHCP on server core, do the following:

1. At a command prompt, type: sc config dhcpserver start= auto
2. Start the service by typing: net start dhcpserver

I thought the 1st command starts DHCP server service automatically. If so, then why do we need net start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sc config dhcpserver start= auto` configures the DHCP server to automatically start up when you boot the machine. However, it does not start the DHCP server if your computer is *already* running.

In order to start the DHCP server on an already running machine, you need the second command: `net start dhcpserver`. Without this second command you would need to reboot the machine before the DHCP server would start.

Comment: So the next time I reboot the machine, DHCP server automatically starts and leases addresses (hence, no need for `net start dhcpserver` at that point)

Comment: @Glowie yes. The `net start dhcpserver` would be unnecessary if you just rebooted the machine after the first command.